# std::abs can be used in constexpr function, but only if it's templated. Why?

Tags: c++, constexpr, function-templates

Supposedly `std::abs` is not `constexpr` in the standard (even in C++20). But in practice I found out that I can compile it as `constexpr` under the very peculiar condition that the function is templated. See this completely working example:

```
template<class T>
constexpr T f(const T input) {
   return std::abs(input);
}

int main() {
   int i = -1;
   int a = f(i);
   return 0;
}
```

The code:

- Compiles fine with GCC, with and without the template.
- It doesn't work in Clang.
- And in Visual Studio it compiles with the template line, but fails compilation without the template.

Comment: No it actually works! Even when invoking. I've used this "trick" without knowing for some time.

Comment: [Clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/nvONlftZIhPngkVN) complains for both cases.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why isn't abs constexpr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27708629/why-isnt-abs-constexpr)

Comment: For more details on why gcc allows this : [Is it a conforming compiler extension to treat non-constexpr standard library functions as constexpr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27744079/is-it-a-conforming-compiler-extension-to-treat-non-constexpr-standard-library-fu)

Comment: Try in MSVC to add `constexpr` to your `i` and `a` - does it compile? If not then `f` is not really a `constexpr` function.

Comment: I mean it's still constexpr if it compiles like that, just not consteval. But it probably shouldn't.

Comment: If it’s not specified such way, then it’s probably not portable. The idea of the function itself seems quite simple, so some compiler might just made them `constexpr`. However you can’t rely on that

Comment: *"I mean it's still constexpr if it compiles like that"* - No, it doesn't mean that. A template declared `constexpr` "falls back" to being non-constexpr if an instantiation is not-constexpr

Comment: Related: [Call non constexpr from constexpr template function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48541044/call-non-constexpr-from-constexpr-template-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For a *regular function*** the compiler may know, based on the type of the function parameters, if the inner code can be potentially evaluated in compile time. This is why you get an error for calling `std::abs` in *MSVC* and *clang*. The behavior of *gcc* is based on its decision to implement `std::abs` as `constexpr` which is by the way [a questionable decision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27744079/is-it-a-conforming-compiler-extension-to-treat-non-constexpr-standard-library-fu).

**For a *template function*** the compiler cannot know if the inner code can be evaluated in compile time, as it may be based on the actual type of the template arguments, with different functions overload being called. While most compilers would decide not to check whether all possible overloads of `std::abs` cannot be `constexpr`, thus letting the code pass compilation, theoretically a compiler may check (in very specific cases that can be checked, like this one) and since the user is not allowed to extend `std` by adding a new version of `abs` (the list of allowed extensions to `std` is closed by the spec) it is possible to see that the function can never be `constexpr` and thus to generate a compilation error. In the more general case however, the compiler cannot check for a template function if all possible cases cannot produce a `constexpr` function, since it sees only the available overloads for the inner call, per each call to the template function, and there might be other available overloads for the inner call, when the template is called elsewhere.

---

Note that making a `constexpr` function a template, just so it can get compiled, would not be a good approach. The actual decision if the function is `constexpr` (i.e. can be called in compile time) would be based on the actual call, and if in all cases the function cannot be `constexpr` you are trying in a way to cheat the compiler but eventually are cheating mainly yourself...

---

By the way, in my check with *clang* 10.1 and trunk versions, I don't get compilation error on the template version, this code [compiles both with gcc and clang](https://godbolt.org/z/Wc5E19):

```
template<typename T>
constexpr T myabs(T t) {
    return std::abs(t);
}

int main() {
    int i = myabs(3);
}
```

While this compiles with gcc (which implements `std::abs` as `constexpr`) and fails with clang:

```
int main() {
    constexpr int i = myabs(3);
}
```

It seems that both *gcc* and *clang* do not generate an error even if the inner call inside a `constexpr` template function is not dependent on the template parameters [and can never be a constant expression](https://godbolt.org/z/vqEz5b):

```
int myabs() {
    return 42;
}

template<class T>
constexpr int f() {
    // this is never a contexpr
    // yet gcc and clang are ok with it
    return myabs();
}
```

And again, this is allowed as no diagnostic is required for non-conforming `constexpr` template functions:

[[dcl.constexpr] 9.2.5/7  - The constexpr and consteval specifiers](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.constexpr#7.sentence-2):

> [...] If no specialization of the template would satisfy the requirements for a constexpr function when considered as a non-template function, the template is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

Comment: In the second case, the function template is ill-formed NDR. No set of template arguments will produce an actual constexpr function (until `std::abs` is made constexpr formally).

Comment: I always thought successful compilation as constexpr means it can at least in theory be run at compile time? Is that assumption wrong?

Comment: @Basti not for a template function, the compiler is not obliged to check all possible overloads and see that it can never be a constexpr, in most cases it cannot actually do that check as it sees only the available overloads per each call to the template function and there might be other available overloads for the inner call, when the template is called elsewhere. There are few cases that it can be checked, like for example when calling directly an std:: function, but then again the compiler is not obliged to check.

Comment: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.constexpr#7.sentence-2

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica would add it to the answer, thanks.